# What is the filter version of "surjective image of ideal is an ideal"

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals

In a commutative ring, the surjective image of an ideal is an ideal. A *filter* in a commutative ring is a saturated multiplicative submonoid. What is the filter analogue of the previous proposition? I don't think the surjective image of a saturated subset is saturated.

Comment: No, I don’t think surjective image of a filter is a filter. Take $\mathbb{Z}$ and $S=\{\pm 7^n\mid n\geq 0\}$. Then map $\mathbb{Z}$ onto $\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z}$. The image of $S$ is $\{\pm \overline{1}\}$, which is not saturated, since $\overline{3}$ is a unit, but not in the image of the set.